# I want to make the phone field auto fill in a format +1 (431) 643-8474 on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The format is working fine but it detects 1 in +1 and override my number with 1's. And it won't let me backspace "+1 (1) -"

```
$('#primary_phone').keyup(function() {
    var phoneNumber = $(this).val();
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // Remove non-digit characters
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(0, 10); // Limit to 10 digits

    var formattedPhoneNumber = '+1 (' + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + phoneNumber.substring(3, 6) + '-' + phoneNumber.substring(6, 10);

    $(this).val(formattedPhoneNumber);
});
```

```
<input type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" title="" tabindex="0" class="phone">
```

Comment: Consider using [Mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: there isn't any option that auto fills "+1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx" x represents the number to be filled everything else is hardcoded

Comment: You can make mask by your own: `$('#primary_phone').mask('+1 (000) 000-0000');`. Check [Basic usage](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#basic-usage)

Comment: I suggest you to delete this question